# Multiple Inheritance Django mixins

Tags: django, generics, multiple-inheritance, mixins

I have an issue with getting Django view to work with two mixins that both override *dispatch* method. 
My view has the following signature:

```
class SomeView(LoggingMixin, ResetUserLanguageMixin, generics.ListAPIView)
```

The *ResetUserLanguageMixin* supposed to set the language in *dispatch*, but then set it back to what it was before the call in *finally* block.

```
class ResetUserLanguageMixin(object):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):    
        cur_language = translation.get_language()

        try:
            response = super(ResetUserLanguageMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            translation.activate(cur_language)

        return response
```

The issue is that *generics.ListAPIView* also has an implementation of *dispatch* that doesn't call super. The *ResetUserLanguageMixin* calls *dispatch*, where it sets the language, but also the finally block is called before the *generics.ListAPIView* *dispatch* is called. As a result incorrect language is used by *generics.ListAPIView*.

The ideal situation would be that *generics.ListAPIView* *dispatch* is called from *ResetUserLanguageMixin's* *dispatch* before the *finally* block. Is this possible, and if so, how could it be accomplished?

Comment: Your diagnosis doesn't seem right. ListAPIView doesn't need to call `super` if it's the last class in the MRO. Why would that cause `finally` to be called first?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The issue was somewhere else.